# Anchor Link to another page on same site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

ive looked on the site many times and cannot find what is going wrong. I need to link from the gallery page to the index page but to specific anchor points in that page.

My index headers

```
<!-- Container (About Section) -->
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
</div>

<!-- Container (Services Section) -->
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid text-center">
</div>
```

Then here is the links on the gallery page.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="/index.html">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="/gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.html#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li><a href="store/index.php">STORE</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.html#ordering">ORDERING</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.html#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? Apparently, everything is fine (assuming that ordering and contact ids exists in your index.html). Are you using browser scroll? If you are using some library for your page scroll (like iScroll, ionic scroll or similar), or if you are adding the ids tags dynamically to your site; the navigation through hashes could fail.

Comment: Looks OK to me, what isn't  working?

Comment: It looks fine, Could you try removing "/"? so instead 
`<li><a href="/index.html#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>`
try `<li><a href="index.html#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>`

Comment: It just doesnt load the page. the URL is www.absolutehtml.com

Comment: Thats due to your javascript

Comment: DarkBee Any idea which part?

Comment: @GeniusboyWonder Have you tried removing the slash at the beginning of your href's?

Comment: Knut Erik - Yea i did still nothing

Comment: Should update your question with the relevant  javascript code to make this question valid though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't navigate in your page due to your javascript.
As it stands now it's trying to get the offset on non-existing item when you click an anchor link from another page. You could change your script to something like this to prevent this

```
$(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    var hash = this.hash;
    if (hash == '' || $(hash).length == 0) return true;

    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 900, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site, you have added some listeners to your `navbar` in order to make an scroll transition when you click on an anchor at your navigation bar to the selected section. This code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
    $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();
        ....
```

There, you are avoiding standard browser behaviour on click over an anchor with hash different from `""`, so it is avoiding redirect to your home when you click on your gallery page to your home page. You should modify this code in order to check if the destination page is the same that your current one, or if you need to go to other page.

Answer (score -1):

try using backslash, or copy the full path. Don't know about using the # though.